# How to validate field for number with percentage only in html5

Tags: html

I want to validate my text box for enter number with percentace.

```
my code is here 

<input type="text" name="tenthmarks" required pattern="[0-9%]" />

It's validate only number but i want like this 25% it means enter number with % sign
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression you have means either a number or a % sign.
You need something like:

```
input type="text" name="tenthmarks" required pattern="[0-9]+%" />
```

Minimal 1 digit and a % sign.